# OKHttp connection with HTTPS

Tags: android, http, mobile, https, okhttp

i used OKHTTP library to communicate with local server, the url of this server was "http://..my ip..my port" and it worked fine but when i changed the url to "https://..server url" to communicate with the prod server the server didn't got my requests at all.

the log show me this error:
"java.io.IOException: stream was reset: REFUSED_STREAM"

i tried to check by postmen communicate with the server and succeed.

Comment: Just check [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in OkHttp 3.3.0.
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2543